# How to prevent a cell from expanding from a wider cell in row beneath it

Tags: html, yui, html-table

I am using the `Yahoo YUI` styling on my pages.

I have the folowing HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text1</td>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td>Text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text4</td>
        <td colspan="2">Text5 Text6 Text7 Text 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The second row's second column is wider than that 2 columns containing Text2 and Text3.  Now because if this the cell containind Text3 is not next to the cell containing Text2.  I need it to be like this but it seems to divide up the space between Text2 and Text3 (because of the longer column beneath it.

I thought that by making it to colspan of 2 would prevent this but it is not working.  I only want the cell containing Text3 to take up the rest of the space.  So what I am looking for is something like:

```
Text1  Text2  Text3
Text4  Text5  Text6  Text7  Text8
```

...and not:

```
Text1  Text2         Text3
Text4  Text5  Text6  Text7  Text8
```

I don't want to specify widths.

Comment: Are you trying to use tables for layout?

Comment: No it's not for a layout.  I have my label in one cell and the textbox in the next cell.

Comment: If the text is left aligned...then the "Text3" should display in the left most area of the cell.  I must not grasp exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Try adding a border to the table tag <table border="1">.

Comment: @John: The width of cells of Text2 and Text3 is divided to take up the space of the wider cell beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to display your table cells inline:

```
td{display:inline;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eGs6h/1/

Alternatively you can float your table cells left.

```
td{float:left;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eGs6h/2/

I prefer the inline method myself.

Comment: What does your second option do, how does it differ from the first option?

Comment: The second option is similar to the first however floating the item to the left causes all the tds to stack up. You'd need to add margins etc to space them out. Displaying them inline makes more sense.

Comment: I'm stuck at the moment, I'm using the Yahoo APIs and when I apply your styles then the table is a mess :(  So I'm not sure what to do.  It looks fine in JS fiddle.

Comment: Try using display:inline-block; instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use `<TD ALIGN="left">` for the Text3 td.

UPDATE:

Ok...I see... Basically, tables automatically size for the contents so your given your html it will stretch the top right 2 cells out (as you described)... Unfortunately, without sizing them you'll be forced to coerce them into appearing correct.  There are probably several ways to do that, but 1 way would be to place Text2 and Text3 in the cell that currently only contains Text2.  Another way would be to add another td cell...

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Text1</td><td>Text2</td><td>Text3</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Text4</td><td colspan=4>Text5 Text6 Text7 Text8</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this case, you'd add enough non-breaking spaces ( ) to stretch out the right hand cell.

[image: Table Image]

Hope that helps...

Comment: The text is left aligned, but it's just the arranging of the cells.